# When do numerical transforms need sample-weighting before applying linear regression

Tags: regression, data-transformation, sample-weighting

- Just wondering if anyone knows of any good resources for sample-weighting in numerical transformations. That is with the intent of using the transformed data in a linear regression model
- I work with times-series data where we weight linear regression models for recency. i.e older data has a lower weight
- This is done using the sample_weight parameter in sklearn LinearRegression
- In preprocessing, if we apply scaling e.g using mean normalization, we use the same sample weights as we use for the regression. This is directly supported by the sklearn StandardScaler
- However there are other transformations we can apply in the model pipeline before we do scaling/model fitting
- Intuitively I feel like at least some of these should be using sample weights in the same way as the scaler/regression-model.
- For example - If we want to use a yeo-johnson transformer. This transformer effectively tries to transform our data to have a gaussian shape. Clearly weighting the data can have an impact on how the yeo-johnson transformer transforms our data. However the implementations of yeo-johnson that i've seen from scipy and feature-engine do not support sample weights. So I'm not sure if there's a good reason that it's been left out or if they just haven't got round to implementing

Comment: IMO weighting for recency is an anti-pattern. weighting essentially corresponds to having more data. if you believe your relationship is non stationary it's better to allow time varying coefficients, then you don't hit all these other problems which arise because of this hack.

Comment: fyi scikit learn generally has for a long time had a problem with sample weights. see https://scikit-learn-enhancement-proposals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/slep006/proposal.html https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4497

Comment: thanks a lot @seanv507. Do time varying coeffs work well for linear models? And do you have any resources/articles you'd reccomend as a starting point? I had a search online but didn't find much outside of some academic papers.
I had a read through the links above. Very interesting, thanks for sharing

Comment: 'time-varying coefficients' is basically just an interaction between time-variable(s) and a regular input variable. (eg  straight line time varying is just adding an extra feature x_i * t). you can use a spline basis of the time variable to model more complicated time varying behaviour (see eg https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_cyclical_feature_engineering.html#modeling-pairwise-interactions-with-splines-and-polynomial-features).

Comment: So the main issue with adding time-variation is that you are adding many more coefficients as is typical with adding interactions. regularisation will help.